# Rails devise gives Rollback message when Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a rails app with devise implemented and everything was running smoothlly and all of the suddent, it stopped saving new users and lost previous ones saved.

Here is the error message given in rails server:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"+sZHDeBr8P64St3ONS75kei4peeuvu4MrXW6TDJWUueEjj1lpv/15HsO+cQUmvVwqu6SX+kJ1ZTmSBqkhb7Zdg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"bcorpas@zohomail.eu", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "bcorpas@zohomail.eu"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 79)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 10.4ms | Allocations: 6146)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
```

> users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    skip_authorization
    @user = current_user
    @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to profile_path
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :photo)
  end
end
```

> user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
  has_many :books
  has_many :loans, through: :books
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

Comment: What is this code even supposed to accomplish? Devise already has a feature for editing user profiles built in.

Comment: @max This is the default code for the Devise template, i didn't change anything...

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by removing this line on user.rb

validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

Answer (score 0):

Devise manage the User Controller for you. you can destroy your `user_controller.rb`
If you need to overwrite and add new behaviour, use the documentation.

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers